# send multiline form with ansible uri module

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to upload a multi-line file to a appdynamics controller, using the ansible uri module.  Any advice?

As you'll notice in the snippets, I'm brand new to Ansible...

It works fine with shell: curl, but I can't seem to get the output correct for a more structured play.

Works

```
- name: import health rule xml via curl
     shell: "curl -i -X POST {{ APPD_HEALTH_RULE_URL }}/{{ APPD_APPLICATIAON_ID }}?overwrite={{ OVERWRITE_EXISTING_RULE }} -H {{ APPD_AUTH_TOKEN }} -F file=@{{ WORKSPACE }}/infrastructure_health_rule_template.xml"
     register: health_rule
```

Doesn't work

```
  - name: import health rule to application
    uri:
      url: "{{ APPD_HEALTH_RULE_URL }}/{{ APPD_APPLICATIAON_ID }}?overwrite={{ OVERWRITE_EXISTING_RULE }}"
      method: POST
      headers: 
        Authorization       : "{{ APPD_TOKEN }}"
        Content-Type        : "multipart/form-data"
      return_content        : yes
      follow_redirects      : all
      body_format           : raw
      body                  : msg="{{lookup('file', '{{ WORKSPACE }}/infrastructure_health_rule_template.xml') }}"
      status_code: 
       - 100
       - 200
       - 201
       - 202
       - 300
       - 301
       - 302
       - 307
    register: health_rule
```

Expected outcome - I'm able to successfully import the health rule to AppD

Actual - I get a 200 response, and nothing happens.

Response:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "age": "0",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content": "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found \n",
    "cookies": {
        "JSESSIONID": "NUMBERS & STUFF"
    },
    "cookies_string": "JSESSIONID=NUMBERS & STUFF",
    "date": "Wed, 25 Sep 2019 20:25:07 GMT",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": "<health-rules controller-version=\"VERSION HERE\">\n  <health-rule>\n    <name>Disk_Space_too_low</name>\n    <type>INFRASTRUCTURE</type>\n    <description/>\n    <enabled>True</enabled>\n    <is-default>false</is-default>\n    <always-enabled>true</always-enabled>\n    <duration-min>35</duration-min>\n    <wait-time-min>35</wait-time-min>\n    <affected-entities-match-criteria>\n        <affected-infra-match-criteria>\n            <type>NODES</type>\n            <node-match-criteria>\n                <type>CUSTOM</type>\n                <match-type>STARTSWITH</match-type>\n                <match-pattern>i-</match-pattern>\n                <inverse>True</inverse>\n                <node-meta-info-match-criteria/>\n                <vm-sys-properties/>\n                <env-properties/>\n            </node-match-criteria>\n        </affected-infra-match-criteria>\n    </affected-entities-match-criteria>\n    <critical-execution-criteria>\n        <entity-aggregation-scope>\n            <type>ANY</type>\n            <value>0</value>\n        </entity-aggregation-scope>\n        <policy-condition>\n            <type>leaf</type>\n            <display-name>Hardware Resources|Volumes|Used %</display-name>\n            <condition-value-type>ABSOLUTE</condition-value-type>\n            <condition-value>90.0</condition-value>\n            <operator>GREATER_THAN</operator>\n            <condition-expression/>\n            <use-active-baseline>False</use-active-baseline>\n            <trigger-on-no-data>False</trigger-on-no-data>\n            <metric-expression>\n                <type>leaf</type>\n                <function-type>VALUE</function-type>\n                <value>0</value>\n                <is-literal-expression>False</is-literal-expression>\n                <display-name></display-name>\n                <metric-definition>\n                    <type>LOGICAL_METRIC</type>\n                    <logical-metric-name>Hardware Resources|Volumes|Used (%)</logical-metric-name>\n                </metric-definition>\n            </metric-expression>\n        </policy-condition>\n    </critical-execution-criteria>\n    <warning-execution-criteria>\n        <entity-aggregation-scope>\n            <type>ANY</type>\n            <value>0</value>\n        </entity-aggregation-scope>\n        <policy-condition>\n            <type>leaf</type>\n            <display-name>Hardware Resources|Volumes|Used %</display-name>\n            <condition-value-type>ABSOLUTE</condition-value-type>\n            <condition-value>80.0</condition-value>\n            <operator>GREATER_THAN</operator>\n            <condition-expression/>\n            <use-active-baseline>False</use-active-baseline>\n            <trigger-on-no-data>False</trigger-on-no-data>\n            <metric-expression>\n                <type>leaf</type>\n                <function-type>VALUE</function-type>\n                <value>0</value>\n                <is-literal-expression>False</is-literal-expression>\n                <display-name></display-name>\n                <metric-definition>\n                    <type>LOGICAL_METRIC</type>\n                    <logical-metric-name>Hardware Resources|Volumes|Used (%)</logical-metric-name>\n                </metric-definition>\n            </metric-expression>\n        </policy-condition>\n    </warning-execution-criteria>\n</health-rule>\n</health-rules>",
            "body_format": "raw",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "all",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Bearer REALLY LONG STRING OF CHARACTERS",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "POST",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": true,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                100,
                200,
                201,
                202,
                300,
                301,
                302,
                307
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "####### URL #######",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
    "redirected": false,
    "server": "AppDynamics",
    "set_cookie": "JSESSIONID=NUMBERS & STUFF; Path=/controller; HttpOnly;Secure",
    "status": 200,
    "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
    "url": "####### URL #######,
    "via": "1.1 varnish",
    "x_content_type_options": "Nosniff",
    "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x_varnish": "1299636501",
    "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `msg=` in the `body` parameter? I think you should ditch that and just use `"{{lookup('file', '{{ WORKSPACE }}/infrastructure_health_rule_template.xml') }}"`

Comment: Good morning @MattP - This produces the same outcome - 200 response - no update to the health rule

Comment: Can you paste the full error message

Comment: Added the controller response (edited to remove tokens and such)

Comment: The error is `no multipart boundary was found`. I notice in your `uri` task you included the header `multipart/form-data` but not in your `curl` command. Have you tried removing/changing the Content-Type header?

Comment: @MattP - I get a 200 response, but nothing happens... I feel like it has something to do with how the data is being passed via curl versus the Ansible uri module. Perhaps there are strings that shouldn't be strings, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still needed. With ansible v2.10 this is possible. What you need is this:

```
- name: import health rule to application
  uri:
    url: "{{ APPD_HEALTH_RULE_URL }}/{{ APPD_APPLICATIAON_ID }}?overwrite={{ OVERWRITE_EXISTING_RULE }}"
    method: POST
    headers: 
      Authorization       : "{{ APPD_TOKEN }}"
      Content-Type        : "multipart/form-data"
    return_content        : yes
    follow_redirects      : all
    body_format           : form-multipart
    body                  : 
      file                : "{{lookup('file', '{{ WORKSPACE }}/infrastructure_health_rule_template.xml') }}"
      filename            : infrastructure_health_rule_template.xml
      mime_type           : application/xml
    status_code: 
     - 100
     - 200
     - 201
     - 202
     - 300
     - 301
     - 302
     - 307
  register: health_rule
```

Notice the `body_format: form-multipart` and the `body` structure. [Check documentation examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#examples). More specific the example: **Upload a file via multipart/form-multipart**